# Selenium 2.53.5 httplib.BadStatusLine: '' Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, httplib

Im trying to automate the registration of serial numbers in an online form using Selenium 2.53.5 in Python 2.7. The script has been working for 2+ months, but yesterday I started receiving an error right when I go to run it: httplib.BadStatusLine: ''. Is there any known fix for this? I've read that leading/trailing new line characters can mess up the retrieving of the url but I can't seem to identify the issue.

Code:

```
import sys
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class SerialSet:
    def __init__(self, fileName, driverPath, user, password):
        self.fn = fileName
        self.failedSerials = []
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)
        self.aloSuccess = False
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def parseSerialFile(self):
        with open(self.fn, 'r') as f:
            self.serials = [line.strip() for line in f]

    def setCountrySN(self, serial, driver):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='USA']").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("serialno").send_keys(serial)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue'][@type='button']").click()

    def submitState(self, driver):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='CT']").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("Continue1").click()

    def login(self, driver):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='accountname']").send_keys(self.user)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='accountpassword']").send_keys(self.password)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signInHyperLink']").click()

    def initiateSN(self, serial, driver):
        # select country and enter serialno
        driver.get("http://supportform.apple.com/201110/")
        self.setCountrySN(serial, driver)

        # enter login
        time.sleep(3)
        if driver.current_url == "http://supportform.apple.com/201110/":
            return False
        self.login(driver)

        # select state and continue
        time.sleep(3)
        self.submitState(driver)

        # final submit
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_id("finalContinue").click()
        return True

    def newSN(self, serial, driver):
        # select country and enter serialno
        driver.get("http://supportform.apple.com/201110/")
        self.setCountrySN(serial, driver)

        # select state and continue
        time.sleep(3)
        if driver.current_url == "http://supportform.apple.com/201110/":
            return False
        self.submitState(driver)

        # final submit
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_id("finalContinue").click()
        return True

    def automateSerials(self):
        for i in self.serials:
            if self.aloSuccess == False:
                if not self.initiateSN(i, self.driver):
                    self.failedSerials.append(i)
                    del i
                else:
                    self.aloSuccess = True
            else:
                if not self.newSN(i, self.driver):
                    self.failedSerials.append(i)
                    del i
        self.driver.quit()
        print(str(len(self.serials) - len(self.failedSerials)) + ":" + str(len(self.serials)))
def main():
    newSet = SerialSet(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
    newSet.parseSerialFile()
    newSet.automateSerials()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automate.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()
  File "automate.py", line 85, in main
    newSet = SerialSet(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
  File "automate.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 401, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 432, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1132, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status
raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Comment: Looks Like they are having a hard time reproducing the problem: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4530

Comment: Chromedriver was updated on 2016-10-22. If it worked before that time but not afterward, then updating chromedriver may fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your using the latest version chromedriver:
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_linux64.zip

I installed chromedriver 2.0 and got this error,

when I upgraded to 2.25 it got rid of this error.

Comment: This still didn't fix the problem for me, I'm still receiving the httplib.BadStatusLine error after chrome attempts to load the first web page.

Comment: At first you was getting the httplib error when calling the chromedriver, now it's happening when you try to load the first page? it could be the website is sending a bad request, did you try loading other websites, like google.com? or bing.com? just to check

Comment: I mean, the website could be sending a bad repsone